# Requiring third party libraries in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm new to Elixir, I'm writing a probabilistic algorithm to learn about the language, but I need to use a external library. I already manage to install it by adding it to the mix.exs file dependencies:

```
 defp deps do
    [{:sfmt_erlang, app: false, git: "https://github.com/jj1bdx/sfmt-erlang.git"}]
 end
```

And it compiled correctly. But how can I use the actual library in my code ? I tried with

`import sfmt_erlang`

but it throws `undefined function sfmt_erlang/0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `Erlang` libraries and code in your Elixir projects, here's the key:

```
:module.method(arguments)
```

Erlang modules are represented as `:atoms` in Elixir code. So you should do this:

```
:sfmt_erlang.your_function(1,2,3)    # You get the idea
```

Also, you might also need to add `:sfmt_erlang` to your list of `applications` in your `mix.exs`

Comment: Yeah it worked! I also needed it to change the name of th application from :sfmt_erlang to :sfmt